# Pivot over rank'ed table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to effectively convert an existing table with a rank over partition column, into a columnar only when there is a rank of 1 and more.  Here's my data:

```
   -------------------------------------
   | Id | Value  | Name          | rank|
   -------------------------------------
   | 1  | 1234   | John          |1    |
   | 2  | 3456   | John          |2    |
   | 3  | 9999   | Chris         |1    |
   | 4  | 9801   | Joe           |1    | 
   | 5  | 1287   | Joe           |2    |
   _____________________________________
```

What I'm trying to arrive at:

```
   -------------------------------------
   |       ValA  | ValB     | Name     | 
   -------------------------------------
   | 1  | 1234   | 3456    | John      |
   | 2  | 9801   | 1287    | Joe       |
   -------------------------------------
```

Tried a few versions of pivot but I feel like I'm missing something.  The key is dropping any rows where rank is only 1, and if I have a 1 & 2, to convert those.

Comment: Post your query you used to get your first table output. This will help.

Comment: It is good if you provide us what you have attempted and the incorrect result you obtained. That can help us to better help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select max(case when rank = 1 then value end) as value_a,
       max(case when rank = 2 then value end) as value_b,
       name
where rank in (1, 2)
group by name
having count(*) = 2;
```

If you want the first column as well, just add `row_number() over (order by (select null))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select rank, name, max(case when rank=1 then value end) as valA,
max(case when rank=2 then value end) as valB
from
(
select * from tablename
where rank in (1,2)
group by id, value, name, rank
having count(distinct rank)=2
)X group by rank, name
```